# Error loading image filepath from the database in django

Tags: python, html, django, image, path

i am starting to use django and i have a little mistake in some of my code but i dont know where is it.

I am trying to load a image from my database in a filepath.

This a part from my models.py that i am using to load the image:

```
class Articulo(models.Model):
    ...
    nombre_imagen=models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

As you can see, i am loading the image from a filepath in my database.

And this is the part of the code that i am trying to do that:

```
{% if articulo %}
      {% for articulo in articulo %}
        ....
          <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" img src="{% static '{{articulo.nombre_imagen}}'}" alt=""></a>
          .....
      {% endif %}
```

The image is located in the static files:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I think there is a stupid problem, but as i said before. I am new at django.

I hope that anyone can help me, thank you!.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't use `models.ImageField()`?

Comment: No i hadn´t, because i don´t know how to use it correctly, so i thought it will works with .CharField. Could you explain me? if you don´t mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you aren't calling the image variable correctly.

```
src="{% static '{{articulo.nombre_imagen}}'}"
```

should be

```
src="{% static articulo.nombre_imagen %}"
```

Also, your image field should be `models.ImageField()`.

```
nombre_imagen=models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

should be

```
nombre_imagen=models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True)
```

Comment: Yes you are right! thanks a lot man. Can you recommend me something to learn this kind of things from django? thank you!.

Comment: The Django Docs are extremely well written, you should check them out! This is about models: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/ and this is about templates: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/#the-django-template-language

Comment: I will check ty!